# What's the most agile way to have the contents of a class displayed for modification

Tags: java, user-interface, agile

In my application I have a couple of classes, called entities, whose main responsibility is to contain data, aswell as use this data in a couple of way by e.g. display the data on a Graphics object or create a XML-document from it. The entities have an aggregation hiearchy with 4 levels.

There is also have a couple of classes, called manipulators, which have a 1-1 relationship with an entity, and they are basicly a JPanel containing JTextFields (or some times JTextAreas) matching the primitive/String fields of their entity, and manipulators matching their entity's composite entities. The manipulators have the same aggregation hiearchy as the entities.

I started implementing "empty" manipulators for creation of entities, and this was quite straight forward, let each parent manipulator call its owned manipulators to create their respective entities.

However, when trying to create manipulators that are pre-entered with the contents of an already existing entity, I ran into a dead end. The options to implement this that I can think of are either letting the entities create the manipulators with setters, let the manipulator get the data from their entity with getters, or use highly-unconveniently long constructors.

Is there some other way to make this happen? If not, which way would be most agile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add getters to the entities.  This way your domain model (entities) don't need to know anything about how they are being displayed.

I would also suggest moving the rendering to a graphics object and creating an XML document to different classes.

Each class should really only have one responsibility.  A class that renders to a graphics object, generates an XML and stores data is trying to manage three separate responsibilities.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

As you divide up classes by responsibility you will also begin to notice new ways to generalize the implementations of those responsibilities and you will end up with a collection of highly reusable components.

For example, I wrote a debug tool that received a message and decoded and displayed its contents.  I started by mistakenly putting both responsibilities, decoding and displaying, into one class.  As soon as I separated those responsibilities, however, I ended up with a new Decoder interface and various implementations that were usable by other components within the system to decode different types of data (Java serialized data, Google Proto buffers encoded data, data encoded by our own in-house middleware).

Comment: Well, I moved the "draw me" and XML functions into the data classes in an effort to remove coupling in the first place. As now I was trying to get rid of getters/setters, but I guess it may have been a misguided effort. I guess that it's ok for the "data" to share its contents then? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Pontus You want to encapsulate things that aren't relevant to a structure's purpose.  For example, the Map interface in Java does not expose (give you access to) the underlying data structures that it uses.  The purpose of a Map is to provide a translation from one value to another in log(n) time, whether it uses arrays, trees or hash tables is largely irrelevant.  If Map had a "getHashTable" method that would vastly limit what you could use as a Map.  Of course sometimes these extra details are relevant so in that case you create specific types (e.g., java's ConcurrentHashMap).